# Web page to add a notice, with some validation

Tags: php, mysql, validation, pdo

I'm displaying multiple queries and `if` statements. In the `if` statement, it increments `notice_category_id` by 1 each time a category is created, but when I code the update/delete/edit (or if truncated), sections won't `rowCount()` increment the row and make duplicates. I'm just wondering if I should change the way the the `notice_category_id` is working. If so, any ideas? Also, how can I display each error message near the field that has the error using the `$assNoticeError` and `$addNoticeErrorMessage`?

I was just wondering if someone could help me make this code simpler.

**MySQL**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `categories`
(
     category_id INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     category_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
      PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
)     ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE notices
(
     notice_id INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     notice_category_id INT(3) NOT NULL, 
     notice_user_id INT(3) NOT NULL, 
     notice_title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     notice_content VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, 
     notice_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
      PRIMARY KEY (notice_id), 
      FOREIGN KEY (notice_category_id)
           REFERENCES categories(category_id), 
      FOREIGN KEY (notice_user_id)
           REFERENCES users(user_id)
)     ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**add_notice.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();

include_once("database/connect.php");

if(empty($_POST["form"])) {
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$query0 = $connection->prepare("SELECT 
                user_id 
                FROM users
                ");
$query0->execute();

$query1 = $connection->prepare("SELECT 
                notice_category_id 
                FROM notices
                ");
$query1->execute();

$notice_category_id = $query1->rowCount();
if($notice_category_id <= $notice_category_id) {
    $notice_category_id++;
};

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $addNoticeError         = array();
    $addNoticeErrorMessage      = "";
    $addNoticeSuccessMessage    = "";

    if(empty($_POST["notice_title"])) {
        $addNoticeError[] = "You must enter a Notice Title.";
    }
    if(empty($_POST["notice_content"])) {
        $addNoticeError[] = "You must enter a Notice Description.";
    }
    if(empty($_POST["category_type"])) {
        $addNoticeError[] = "You must select a Category Type.";
    }
    if(!empty($addNoticeError)) {
        foreach($addNoticeError as $error) {
            $addNoticeErrorMessage .= $error . '<br />';
        }
    } else {
        if(!isset($error)) {
            $category_type = $_POST['category_type'];

            $query2 = "INSERT INTO categories (category_type) VALUES (:category_type)";
            $query2 = $connection->prepare($query2);
            $query2->bindParam(":category_type", $_POST["category_type"], PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
            $query2->execute();


            $notice_category_id = $_POST['notice_category_id'];
            $notice_user_id     = $_POST['notice_user_id'];
            $notice_title       = $_POST['notice_title'];
            $notice_content     = $_POST['notice_content'];

            $query3 = "INSERT INTO notices (notice_category_id, notice_user_id, notice_title, notice_content) VALUES (:notice_category_id, :notice_user_id, :notice_title, :notice_content)";
            $query3 = $connection->prepare($query3);
            $query3->bindParam(":notice_category_id"    , $_POST["notice_category_id"]      , PDO::PARAM_INT, 3);
            $query3->bindParam(":notice_user_id"        , $_POST["notice_user_id"]      , PDO::PARAM_INT, 3);
            $query3->bindParam(":notice_title"      , $_POST["notice_title"]        , PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
            $query3->bindParam(":notice_content"        , $_POST["notice_content"]      , PDO::PARAM_STR, 500);
            $query3->execute();

            header("Location: notices.php");
        }
    }
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Add a Notice</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if(!empty($addNoticeErrorMessage)) : ?>
    <p><?php echo $addNoticeErrorMessage ?></p>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if(!empty($addNoticeSuccessMessage)) : ?>
    <p><?php echo $addNoticeSuccessMessage ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
    <h4>Add a Notice</h4>
    <form method="post" name="add_notice" action="">
        <input name="notice_category_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $notice_category_id; ?>" />
        <input name="notice_user_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" />
        <input type="text" name="notice_title" id="notice_title" placeholder="notice title" maxlength="25" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["notice_title"])) { echo htmlentities($_POST["notice_title"]); } ?>" />
        <br />
        <textarea name="notice_content" id="notice_content" placeholder="notice content"/><?php if(isset($_POST["notice_content"])) { echo htmlentities($_POST["notice_content"]); } ?></textarea>
        <br /><br />
        <select name="category_type">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                <option value="Content1">Content1</option>
                <option value="Content2">Content2</option>
                <option value="Content3">Content3</option>
                <option value="Content4">Content4</option>
                <option value="Content5">Content5</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="hidden" name="add_notice">
        <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit">Add a new Notice</button>
    </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 6):

## Good things

You are using `PDO` with parameterized queries, which is a really good thing. That should save you potential troubles between the application and the database. Kudos.

## Dead query

This query is never used:

> ```
> $query0  = $connection->prepare("SELECT 
>             user_id 
>             FROM users
>             ");
> $query0->execute();
> ```

There is no point in getting all the user IDs from the database at this point if you don't reuse it later. Dead code should be removed.

## Row count

This part doesn't need to be this tortuous:

> ```
> $query1 = $connection->prepare("SELECT 
>             notice_category_id 
>             FROM notices
>             ");
> $query1->execute();
> $notice_category_id = $query1->rowCount();
> if ($notice_category_id <= $notice_category_id) {
>     $notice_category_id++;
> };
> ```

So what you are doing is:

1. Get all the `notice_category_id`
2. Count them
3. Check that a value is lesser than or equal to itself (A value will always equal itself no matter what)
4. Increment by one to the next ID

That could all be done in one step (plus assignment from execution):

```
$query1 = $connection->prepare("SELECT MAX(notice_category_id) + 1 FROM notices")
$notice_category_id = $query1->execute();
```

You get the idea, I think.

Note, if you are using MySQL, which I believe is the case, there is [another trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1405500/3626537), which is more natural as it will ask the database to give you the next ID (assuming the ID columns are auto-increment, which is generally the case), and that should prevent any duplication as well as take account of deleted records and such.

> ```
> SELECT auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE
> table_name = 'the_table_you_want'
> ```

So we could do something like this:

```
$query1 = $connection->prepare("SELECT auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables where table_name = 'notices'");     
$notice_category_id = $query1->execute();
```

## Naming Things

There are several things which could use better names.

> ```
>     $addNoticeError          = array();
>     $addNoticeErrorMessage   = "";
>     $addNoticeSuccessMessage = "";
> ```

Those variables don't *add* any notices, they just contain them. Therefore, this would make more sense:

```
    $errors = array();
    $errorMessage = "";
    $successMessage = "";
```

Your queries are also not named very well. Instead of numbering them, just name them according to what they do...

```
$selectAllUserIds                 // instead of $query0
$selectAllNoticeCategoryIds       // instead of $query1
$selectNextNoticeCategoryId       // instead of the above refactored $query1
$insertCategoryType               // instead of $query2
$insertNotice                     // instead of $query3
```

The rest of the code looks pretty decent I think. I noticed `$addNoticeSuccessMessage` is also never used. Perhaps you intended to complete this later.

Comment: thank you I made the changes! Also I added my MySQL in the main post. With notice_category_id it is a foreign key so with $query1 = $connection->prepare("SELECT MAX(notice_category_id) + 1 FROM notices")
$notice_category_id = $query1->execute(); that adds an increment to the database so I need to do another SELECT query when someone creates another noitce? because it doesn't increment the hidden field it stays as 1 but increments the database

Comment: Ah, concurrency is what you are dealing with, then? In that case, it would be better to get the `category_id` from the primary table once you insert a record in it, and then use that value as the foreign key in the other table. Look up [`mysql_insert_id`](http://au.php.net/mysql_insert_id), it's made specifically for that purpose.

Comment: oh okay no idea ha but i'll give it ago can I use PDO::lastInsertId? as I specially need to use PDO

Comment: I didn't know PDO had an equivalent, my bad! Yes, by all means, go with `PDO::lastInsertId` that's even better!

Comment: I'm having some trouble with lastInsertId() it keeps returning 0 and when i click the button to create a notice it gives a mysql error and doesn't add a notice but adds the category_id everytime

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but; are you making sure you insert the category ID first, get the lastInsertId afterwards, and _then_ use that ID to create a notice?

Comment: this is what i done and everytime i refresh/load the page it adds another key to the database  
$category_id = "";
  $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO categories (category_id) VALUES (?)");
  $query->bindValue(1, $category_id);
  
  if($query->execute()) {
   $notice_category_id = $connection->lastInsertId();
  }

Comment: @natluf if you have a specific programming issue, feel free to search/ask on [so]. This conversation is outside the scope of Code Review.

Answer (score 3):

This statement here is completely redundant:

> ```
> $notice_category_id = $query1->rowCount();
> if($notice_category_id <= $notice_category_id) {
>     $notice_category_id++;
> };
> ```

Why on Earth do you need to check if something is less than or equal *to itself*!? The above chunk of could should simply become the following one-liner:

```
$notice_category_id = $query1->rowCount() + 1;
```

Also, I've noticed that many of your variables are phrased like functions, which are commonly statements beginning with a verb. A few examples are:

- `$addNoticeError`
- `$addNoticeErrorMessage`
- `$addNoticeSuccesMessage`

You should probably just drop the `add` from these.

Credit goes to user [@Phrancis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42632/phrancis) for finding these.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is a bit strange:

> ```
> $addNoticeError         = array();
> $addNoticeErrorMessage      = "";
> $addNoticeSuccessMessage    = "";
> ```

> ```
>         $query3->bindParam(":notice_category_id"    , $_POST["notice_category_id"]      , PDO::PARAM_INT, 3);
>         $query3->bindParam(":notice_user_id"        , $_POST["notice_user_id"]      , PDO::PARAM_INT, 3);
>         $query3->bindParam(":notice_title"      , $_POST["notice_title"]        , PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
>         $query3->bindParam(":notice_content"        , $_POST["notice_content"]      , PDO::PARAM_STR, 500);
> ```

---

You can use `array_join` instead:

> ```
>     foreach($addNoticeError as $error) {
>         $addNoticeErrorMessage .= $error . '<br />';
>     }
> ```

```
$addNoticeErrorMessage = array_join($addNoticeError, '<br />');
```